# How to call a javascript function from html button in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a button in my chrome extension

```
<input type="submit" value="Refresh Page" title="Submit" style="width: 210px; height: 60px;"/>
```

When I click it, I want it to call this function in a separate javascript file:

```
function click (0) {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    var code = 'window.location.reload();';
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: code});
});}
```

I don't know if the code goes in the html file or javascript file :/ I'm really new to javascript and the chrome api so some help would be really cool.

Comment: Last time I worked on chrome extensions you could not do this since it's a security concern. Hopefully this is no longer the case.

Comment: @DanielWilliams So what were buttons used for if you couldn't use them for Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome Extensions, you are not allowed to have `inline` scripts since it violates their policies. Instead you will have to do it as follows:

## Your HTML file

`<button type="button" id="create">do something</button>`

## Your javascript file

```
$('#create').bind('click', some_function());

function some_function() {
    ... //your on_click code here. What to do when button is clicked
}
```

`rest of your javascript codes`

## [CHANGED]

```
$('#create').click(function do_something(){
    ... //your code here to refresh the page.
});
```

Comment: Where do I put $('#create').bind('click', some_function());

Comment: In your javascript file. Anywhere really. Not in a function though, @TreB, just lying outside

Comment: Nothing's happening, though it may be my javascript. Is this the correct html code to link to my .js file: <script src="popup.js"></script> I made sure the names were correct too.

Comment: @TreB, Yes, However, your `<script src="popup.js"></script>` line should come after you have created the button.

Comment: Is there a way to check if the function is being called? Thanks for all the help by the way.

Comment: Add a `document.write('Hello')` line as the first line of the function

Comment: @TreB, That is a very valid question. It will just write it to the .html file page. You should see it on your html page

Comment: I don't see anything. It's a popup window by the way.

Comment: @TreB, Can you provide a jsfiddle code for all your codes. Thanks

Comment: @TreB, I think there is a problem with opening and closing tags.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is reload the current page.

Comment: @TreB, I have changed my answer, check it out.

Comment: @TreB, just put your refreshing code in there and it should work

Comment: Still nothing, but I'm really thinking it's my refresh code, I got it off the internet.